# how we give error message when user enters string value in text box which accepts only integers

Tags: spring

I have jsp page which contains one text box which is accepting only integers. That means i have command object which is having integer property. when user enter string in the box.how spring reacts.

Comment: I should suggest if you use `JSP` then used JavaScript validation plugins like `Parsley.js` [http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#validators]

Answer (score 0):

Use Spring form tag library. When Spring binds a property and there is a type mismatch it adds a field error to the model with error code typeMismatch

Example

//form object

```
public class Person{

   private int age;

   //getters and setters
}


@Controller
@RequestMapping("/person")
public class PersonController{

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String showPersonForm(Model model){
     Person person = new Person();
     model.addAttribute("person" , person";
     return "person";
  }

  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String savePerson(Person person , BindingResult bindingResult){
     if(bindingResult.hasErrors()){
        return "person";
     }
     //return success url
  }
}
```

//person.jsp

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="person" >
        <form:input path="age" type="text" />
        <form:errors path="age" />
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form:form>
```

You will need to define a MessageSource bean in your application context to allow for resolution of your error messages for example using Java Config

```
@Bean
public MessageSource messageSource(){
   ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames("errors");
return resourceBundleMessageSource;
}
```

The errors.properties file should be in the root of the application context

//errors.properties

```
typeMismatch=The value you entered is invalid #for all type mismatches
typeMismatch.age=The age you have entered is invalid #for field specific type mismatched
```